# ESLint and WebStorm Code Style/Inspections

Tags: webstorm

Can someone confirm that the ESLint rules (including using plugins like Prettier with ESLint) is something different from *Editor* > *Code Style* and *Editor* > *Inspections* in WebStorm?

For example in WebStorm you can set *Hard wrap at* in Code Style to 100

[image]

and you can configure Prettier `printWidth` of 90.

[image]

There is not conflict here is there? or anything like this?

---

Edit:

Prettier configuration in Webstorm 2023.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured ESLint to use Prettier config, and then use IDE code style settings to reformat code, your will see linter errors because the resultant print width won't match Prettier settings. Unfortunately it's hardly possible to set up the IDE code style preferences to match Prettier's code style exactly. Prettier is an opinionated formatter without a spec, with stylistic changes introduced in patch releases, we can hardly match each and every IDE formatter option with Prettier/ESLint ones. To avoid conflicts/linter errors, you can set up Prettier as your [default formatter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/prettier.html#ws_prettier_default_formatter) to get your code reformatted with Prettier on **Code > Reformat Code**.

Comment: I do not have the disable/automatic/manual configuration options in Language & Frameworks > JavaScript > Prettier, which is detailed in the documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/prettier.html#ws_prettier_configure. I am on version 2023.1. See image added above. It is not clear to me how I set Prettier as my default formatter, as suggested?

Comment: you must be using some older IDE version; please tick the  **On 'Reformat Code' action** checkbox to make Prettier your default formatter